# Difference between AngularJS ui.router views property and child states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between having children like this:

```
.state('bleh',
views {view1, view2, etc. with relevant properties})
```

And having them like this:

```
.state('bleh')
.state('bleh.view1')
.state('bleh.view2')
```

With relevant properties

?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that they are two alternatives for the same thing.

In here you are indicating, which views are associated with 'bleh' state. 
In other word, which views will be 'refreshed'.

Use the views property to set up multiple views. If you do not need multiple views within a single state this property is not needed.

```
.state('bleh',
views {view1, view2, etc. with relevant properties})
```

And, in here you are indicating a nested state. The state `view1` is a child of the above "bleh" state.

```
.state('bleh')
.state('bleh.view1')
.state('bleh.view2')
```